# How to find all files in a folder w/o the folder itself

Tags: linux, shell, find

I tried the following commands:

```
>> ls abc
1  2  3
>> find abc -name "*" -print0
abcabc/1abc/2abc/3
>> find abc -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 ls
abc/1  abc/2  abc/3

abc:
1  2  3
```

It seems that `.` is also found by find if I use `*`. Can we ask find not to return `.`?

I also tried `-not -path "."`. It does not work.

Comment: If you're not interested in folders, but only files, then perhaps `find abc -type f` would be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the **minimal depth** relative to the starting point(s) you specify:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/b a/c
$ find a -mindepth 1 -name "*"
a/c
a/b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also restrict to only files by using the `-type f` primary this way:

```
$ mkdir abc
$ touch abc/{1..3}
$ ls abc
1   2   3
$ find abc -type f 
abc/1
abc/2
abc/3
```

Then `find` will only show directories as part of the showing of file paths:

```
$ mkdir abc/efg
$ mkdir abc/xyz
$ touch abc/efg/{4..6}
$ find abc -type f 
abc/1
abc/2
abc/3
abc/efg/4
abc/efg/5
abc/efg/6
```

Last example neither `.` or `abc/xyz` are shown.

Comment: ... or `! -type d`! This will permit use of *symlinks*, *devices* or *pipes*, for sample...